# Conflict with jquery script

Tags: jquery

I'm not an expert in jQuery. I have a problem: when I insert a slider the scripts that are located at the bottom no longer work.

This is the link [without](http://www.egocreative.it/uni_demo2/) and [with](http://www.egocreative.it/uni_demo1/) the slider.

I tried it with jqueryNoconflict, but nothing!

I see there are many problems in the Google Chrome console, can you help me?

Comment: Can you provide a shortened version of your problem on jsfiddle.com?

Comment: You would do better to post the relevant parts of your code here rather than expect people to visit your website. Even better, set up a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) with your code so people can play with it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the essential parts of the code inside the question.

Comment: You can help yourself by looking at javascript console in browser. I see more than couple of issues when I open console.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As others ahead of me have said, you really need to ask a specific question as debugging a site isn't a 30 second job.

Comment: thanks everyone, i'm sorry, i'm not a jquery expert, really... I will try to be more detailed next time, thanks for your understanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking the console (for example with Firebug) there are the errors:

```
$(".accordion, .tabs").TabsAccordion is not a function
/uni_demo1/ (row 1338)

jQuery("video,object").maximage is not a function
jQuery('video,object').maximage('maxcover');

(nothing to output)
video.js (row 21)

a is null
...var Ah=zh(-fa,-fa,fa,fa),Bh=zh(0,0,0,0);function Ch(a,b,c){if(a=a[db](b))c=q.pow...
main.js (row 28)

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.egocreative.it/uni_demo1/video/vid/camera.mp4"
```

You must:

1. sanitize your code by checking opened/closed tags balancing
2. check if your scripts run on `$(document).ready`
3. check on what object you want to activate `TabsAccordion`, there are no element with class accordion or tabs; seems a copy of the demo? (http://lamovo.com/support/tabs+accordion#usage)
4. check the selector used for the maximage plugin (http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/)
5. check if your web server is serving correctly all the resources

Answer (score 1):

Fix your site, it's full of unopened tags, also create just one jQuery object per element you want to use, for example this:

```
$('.accordion, .tabs').TabsAccordion...
```

Is better like this:

```
$('.accordion').TabsAccordion...
$('.tabs').TabsAccordion...
```

Also, it seems that some of the jQuery objects that you are trying to create don't exists in the source, apearrently there is no elements with `accordion` or `tabs` CSS classes.

By the way, if you don't see the unopened tags, open your site in Internet Explorer and hit F12, you should see the errors i mentioned in the Console.

Comment: `.TabsAccordion()` does not seem to exist as a method either.